# LinQ OrderBy returning System.NullReferenceException when used with field of a property inside the item

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ienumerable

The model `Monsters` contains a field of type `JewelDrop` which contains a field of type `float` with the name `BlessDrop`.

I am trying to sort a List of type `Monster` based on the value inside `Monster.JewelDrop.BlessDrop` but whenever I try doing it I get a `NullReferenceException`

This is what I have tried doing so far, which gives me this exception:

`return monsters.OrderByDescending(x => x.JewelDrop.SoulDrop).FirstOrDefault();`

There is no difference if I use `First();` or `FirstOrDefault();`

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Monster
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MonsterLevel { get; set; }
        public int Hp { get; set; }
        public int MinDmg { get; set; }
        public int MaxDmg { get; set; }
        public int MinEleDmg { get; set; }
        public int MaxEleDmg { get; set; }
        public int Defense { get; set; }
        public int EleDefense { get; set; }

        public JewelDrop JewelDrop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class JewelDrop
    {

        public int MonsterLevel { get; set; }
        public float BlessDrop { get; set; }
        public float SoulDrop { get; set; }
        public float LifeDrop { get; set; }
        public float CreationDrop { get; set; }
        public float ChaosDrop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error says `JewelDrop` is null.

Comment: Yes, but when I debug I see that it is infact NOT null.

Comment: `monsters` is null or `JewelDrop` is null. That's the only way the code you have will produce that exception.

Comment: As I'm not entirely familiar with the data it appears that SOME Monster objects can end up with null jeweldrop fields and as a result the error - the elvis operator is the solution in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like either one of your monsters is null, or more likely, has a null JewelDrop value.

try

```
return monsters.OrderByDescending(x => x?.JewelDrop?.SoulDrop).FirstOrDefault();
```

See https://csharp.today/tag/elvis-operator/